# Why does a string connected between a D0-brane and an anti-D0-brane turn into a tachyon upon their annihilation?

Tags: string-theory, branes

Consider a string stretched between a D0-brane and an anti-D0-brane. In this case as the stretching energy is greater than the quantum zero point energy the string will have a positive mass. But, as the D0-brane and the anti-D0-brane come closer to annihilate the string becomes a tachyon as now the major is from quantum zero point energy as the string is no longer stretched.

But will the sudden "coming closer" of the brane and anti-brane give the string extra vibrations?

If so,is it that the energy due to these vibrations is not enough to overcome that of zero point energy finally resulting in a tachyon?

Comment: As Ron Maimon just explained [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/18264/string-connected-between-brane-brane-tachyon-annihilation?show=18286#a18286), the D0 branes of the system act as static (positive energy)sources, that feed the condensation of more and more (negative mass) tachyons that get stuck on the two branes. After the annihilation of the Do branes, nothing is left of the system. In this perturbative picture, there is no back reaction, so the strings to not get into excited vibrational states.